# Error 200 with websockets javascript

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, websocket, azure-web-app-service

I'm working on a project with some Arduino's and motion sensors. The arduino's send their data to an IoThub on azure. Now I have a working webpage which collects the data and shows them in a SVG-floor plan. This webpage just contains a html index and some JS files to talk to the server. Now I want to implement this in an ASP.net webapp to add some more functionality. But now it comes, I did exactly the same as with the normal webpage. Same JS-files etc. But now when I run the app I got an error:

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://sensordash-wa.azurewebsites.net/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200

Here is the working webpage:
[image]

And here is the not working asp.net webapp with exactly the same JS-files etc. :
[image]

I think that everything on the Azure-side is working well but i'm missing something in the asp.net app. 
Thanks in advance!

Server.js:

```js
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const moment = require('moment');
const path = require('path');
const iotHubClient = require('Scripts//iot-hub.js');

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(function (req, res/*, next*/) {
  res.redirect('/');
});

const server = http.createServer(app);
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });

// Broadcast to all.
wss.broadcast = function broadcast(data) {
  wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
    if (client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
      try {
        console.log('sending data ' + data);
        client.send(data);
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
    }
  });
};

var iotHubReader = new iotHubClient(process.env['Azure.IoT.IoTHub.ConnectionString'], process.env['Azure.IoT.IoTHub.ConsumerGroup']);
iotHubReader.startReadMessage(function (obj, date) {
  try {
    console.log(date);
    date = date || Date.now()
    wss.broadcast(JSON.stringify(Object.assign(obj, { time: moment.utc(date).format('YYYY:MM:DD[T]hh:mm:ss') })));
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(obj);
    console.error(err);
  }
});

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
server.listen(port, function listening() {
  console.log('Listening on %d', server.address().port);
});

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Folder structure:
[image]

Script folder structure:

[image]

web.config:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>


  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="LiveDash" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
      <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
      <webSocket
     enabled="true"
     receiveBufferLimit="true"
     pingInterval="00:01:00">
      </webSocket>
      
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.web>
    <compilation>
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Are your `Server.js`  deployed on azure web app as your websocket server ? I tried to connect your endpoint via `var socket = new WebSocket("wss://sensordash-wa.azurewebsites.net");` and I could reproduce your issue. I tried to build my node.js backend and deploy to azure web app, then enable **Web sockets** under "SETTINGS > Application settings" of my web app, then I could receive data from my single html file locally. If I misunderstand your scenario, please correct me. Also, you could provide more details for us to narrow this issue.

Comment: Yes my Server.js is deployed within the asp.net app. I've the same issue, my single html file is working fine but when I do it in a .net app I get this issue.

Comment: Could you share the folder structure of your asp.net app deployed to azure web app?

Comment: Lol, as we speak I got it working (Websocket connects now) I only don't get the incoming messages.

Comment: But @BruceChen I don't know where to place my files Server.js and IoTHub.js

Comment: Can you please post your web.config?

Comment: Added it. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I checked this issue and tested it on my azure web app. Based on my test, you could use url rewrite rule to rewrite the request with the specific path to be handled by node.js. For more details, you could refer to the following details.

**The structure of website content under my Azure Web App:**

[image]

**Web.config with the url rewrite rule:**

[image]

**MVC view page:**

[image]

**Test result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks sir! Works like a charm